# Confusion regarding usage of event.triggered

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying out some code that is supposed to block until moving to a new simulation time step (similar to waiting for `sys.tick_start` in *e*).

I tried writing a function that does this:

```
  task wait_triggered();
    event e;
    `uvm_info("DBG", "Waiting trig", UVM_NONE)
    -> e;
    $display("e.triggered = ", e.triggered);
    wait (!e.triggered);
    `uvm_info("DBG", "Wait trig done", UVM_NONE)
  endtask
```

The idea behind it is that I trigger some event, meaning that its `triggered` field is going to be 1 when control reaches the line with `wait(!e.triggered)`. This line should unblock in the next time slot, when `triggered` is going to be cleared.

To test this out I added some other thread that consumes simulation time:

```
fork
  wait_triggered();

  begin
    `uvm_info("DBG", "Doing stuff", UVM_NONE)
    #1;
    `uvm_info("DBG", "Did stuff", UVM_NONE)
  end
join
#1;
$finish(1);
```

I see the messages *Doing stuff* and *Did stuff*, but *Wait trig done* never comes. The simulation also stops before reaching the `finish(1)`. One simulator told me that this is because no further events have been scheduled.

All simulators exhibit the same behavior, so there must be something I'm missing. Could anyone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with `wait (!e.triggered);` when `e.triggered` is changing from 1 to zero. It has to change in a region where nothing can be scheduled, so whether it changes at the end of the current time slot, or the beginning of the next time slot is unobservable. So the `wait` will hang waiting for the end of the current time slot, which never comes.

I think the closest thing to what you are looking for is `#1step`. This blocks for the smallest simulation precision time step. But I've got to believe there is a better way to code what you want without having to know if time is advancing.

Comment: I was just wondering that `fork...join` is completed that means all the threads must complete. Then how come the display not arrive? Also, the event seems to be triggered in NBA region, thereafter, simulation jumps to Active region for `$display`. And `wait--triggered`  waits for entire time stamp. So, the task must exit after `1step` delay. But this doesn't seem to be happening, can you please tell am I right and elaborate on that?

Comment: The way event-driven simulation works is that any timing control `#, @`, or `wait` has to be notified to **wake up** and there is never a notification to the `wait` statement that `e.triggered` changed from 1 to 0, so no evaluation of the expression `!e.triggered`. So the process calling the task `wait_triggered()` hangs, it never completes. So the `fork/join` never completes. The

Comment: The call to `uvm_wait_for_nba_region` is unnecessary  with the code shown.
This is why I strongly recommend against using #0, #1, #1step in your code unless you have a very good understanding of Verilog's scheduling algorithms. The UVM is full of unnecessary #0's and makes it difficult for people trying to modify the behavior to know exactly what it is doing. I would also try to avoid named events. There is usually a better, easier to maintain way of coding it.

Comment: Oh now I got. The `fork..join` never exits. There must be a transition of `e.triggered` from 1 to 0 in **same time stamp**. In the time stamp where event is triggered, the `wait` statement gets a `1` in `e.triggered` and in the subsequent time stamp, it gets a `0`. So, there is **no transition** from 1 to 0 in **single** time stamp, hence it blocks. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Yes I too don't believe in using the `#0` or `#1` or any other manual workarounds. It makes things easy but makes them fuzzy too.

Comment: @dave_59 The `uvm_wait_for_nba_region()` call was an artifact from when I was trying to play around. The code was just an example I was trying to work out in my mind. I'm not a big fan of all these delays either.